# All apple devices, and only apple devices, suddenly unusably slow on home network wifi internet

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, ipad, network

Starting approximately 24 hours ago all my apple devices (macbook air, iphone 6+, ipad original (ios5)) all had an internet connection so slow as to be unusable. Nothing's miraculously changed overnight unfortunately.

2 windows laptops & a windows smartphone are all fine.

Took my iphone and macbook air into town and connected to a wifi hotspot okay yesterday afternoon. This tells me it's probably some random combination of apple devices and my router (or ISP I guess). ISP is skinnydirect which uses Spark network. I'm in New Zealand.

There'd been no software updates applied to any of the 3 apple devices recently. The ipad can't be updated. The iphone now has the latest update and it made no difference.

We're rural. We have a Huawei wifi router with a 3g sim to provide our internet connection. It's the simplest router you can find I think though it's a little old now. There's been no recent updates to the router available or installed.

I've tried turning everything off, then resetting; forgetting networks; resetting networks on the iphone; changing the channel on the router; changing the dns servers to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.4. All random suggestions from others with similar problems but none have made any difference.

Scratching my head over what to try and how to fix this so any ideas will be welcome.

Comment: Are things fine between devices on the intranet? Is it just going out to the internet?

Comment: Good question. I've just checked intranet performance and it's fine. i.e. I airdropped a photo from the iphone to the macbook and it was fast.